# gitignore does not ignore .DS_Store files

Tags: gitignore

why gitignore does not ignore .DS_Store files ?

this is my .gitignore file

```
#Directory based project format
.idea

# Ignore Mac DS_Store files
**/.DS_Store

#node modules for grunt
node_modules

#files generated with grunt
src/app.js
```

this works for node modules and src/app.js perfect, but does not ignore DS_Store.

Can anybody tell me why ?

Comment: Did you already commit it once? You can't ignore files that are part of the repo

Comment: Yes, I already commit it. How can I delete them from repo and from all branches ?

Answer (score 3):

Use this command to delete a file from the repo, but not delete the file itself:

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

After you removed it, you can ignore it using .gitignore.

Comment: It works. Thank you. But I already remove .DS_Store file from bitbucket and now cant push my changes. What can I do ?

Comment: You could force a push, with `git push --force` but I'm not sure if that is the safest option here.

Comment: The best way would be to check out the version that is on your bitbucket, so there are no changes between your local and remote files. When that is done, it should be no problem to push changes back to bitbucket.

Comment: Didnt help, I deleted file from bitbucket from branch origin/Gor, now I am on branch Gor, I cant push it reverse bitbucket commit

Answer (score 0):

The overall reason for this is because you had already added the DS_Store file and that you need to commit the new changes prior to adding it to the .gitignore file. However, there's another way of getting around that.

git currently gives a hint that is very helpful in this situation.

use "git restore ..."

The way I fixed this particular issue was using the `git restore` command followed by the .DS_Store filename.

`git restore .DS_Store` fixed this issue for me.

[image]